# jquery drag and drop with database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drag-and-drop

I'm working on drag and drop and store id number in database, i just finished that and is works great in all browser but the problem is that is NOT WORKING IN IE 8 or 9.

The problem is that in IE is not allow me to drag or move around that the problem that i can't figure out how to solve this, and rest of browser are works fine.

here is jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
   function slideout(){
  setTimeout(function(){
  $("#response").slideUp("slow", function () {
      });

}, 2000);}

    $("#response").hide();
 $(function() {
 $("#list ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.8, cursor: 'move', update: function() {

 var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&update=update'; 
 $.post("updateList.php", order, function(theResponse){
 $("#response").html(theResponse);
 $("#response").slideDown('slow');
 slideout();
 });   
 }   
 });
 });

}); 
</script>
```

and the body code is

```
    <div id="response"> </div>
    <ul>
      <?php
                include("connect.php");
 $query  = "SELECT id, text FROM dragdrop ORDER BY listorder ASC";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {

 $id = stripslashes($row['id']);
 $text = stripslashes($row['text']);

 ?>
      <li id="arrayorder_<?php echo $id ?>"><?php echo $id?> <?php echo $text; ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

can any one help me how to solve to make works drag and drop for IE, if is there is other sample that might support all browser!

AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @jheilgeist here, adding a position:relative on the div, will sort it out, even if it acts a little weird.

It looks like a jQuery UI bug in those browsers.

Check more info here: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7546

Comment: i have tried that position:relative on the div is does not working... any other idea!

Comment: Please try this example in IE9 and let me know if it works: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

If it does, you just need to re-adapt it to your needs.

Comment: No problem :) if this solved your question, please mark my answer as the correct answer! Thanks and have a nice day!